# Add custom meta tag to Virtuemart category page

Tags: php, meta-tags

I am use virtumeart and need insert custom meta tag for category pages.

I try change com_virtuemart/category/default.php and add

```
<meta name="ContentKing" content="Category">
```

file is here:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oDrPnycCSohOSRjywXAsMMo0n7oVi_R3/view?usp=sharing
```

any solution?